# C# ADO.NET for single SQL operation necessary to rollback transaction on exception?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ado.net, commit, rollback

I wrap my single SQL write operation in a `SqlTransaction`

If an exception occurs on `SqlCommand.ExcuteNonQuery()` , is it necessary to call `SqlTransaction.Rollback()` ?

On exception, what state is the `SqlTransaction` left in ? Will `SQL Server` rollback the operation on its own ?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction state will depend on the error severity.  Some SQL Server errors will rollback the transaction automatically and others may not.  I suggest you invoke the Rollback method within a try/catch within the outer exception block.